# How do I create a robust FTP connection using commons-net

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

We've had a lots of issues where our ftp connection hangs indefinitely, causing the program to hang.

How do I configure FTPClient to not do this?

Comment: That really depends on why it is hanging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'm thinking so far.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.setDataTimeout(timeout);
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // otherwise the connect call might hang
ftpClient.connect(this.serverAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to switch to passive mode: I've observed that it tends to hang badly if you are going through a firewall and don't switch to passive mode.